# Function to select, insert or update from sqlite3

Tags: c#, sqlite

I need know a function to use the sqlite3 the function i want to use is like this:

```
public class<T> public Task<list<T>>getDB()
{
  _sqLiteConnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().
  var Query = sqLiteConnection.Table<T>().ToList();
  return Query;
}
```

but the error messages is:

> CS0310 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless >>constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   SQLiteConnection.Table()`

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the `Table` method has a constraint that limits what types are acceptable for `T`. You can fix the problem by adding the same constraint to your method:

```
public Task<List<T>> getDB<T>() 
    where T : new()
{
    ...
}
```

If your *class* defines `T`, you would need to apply the constraint to the class instead:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : new()
{ 
    public Task<List<T>> getDB()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```